# Stack Overflow: unable to to 'Post a Question'

Tags: support

I am trying to post a question regarding Mysql.

I have finished editing it and previewing it- it looks alright to me. However, in the last step (image below), once I click the  the Stack Overflow(SO)  button called 'Post your question' , 2-3 dots appear to move to the right- they look like a process is in progress, but this process doesn't end. These  dots haven't stopped moving, while the 'Post your question' option gets grayed out.

I find these 2-3 moving since 1 hour and my question hasn't been posted yet. However, SO has saved it as a draft. Please help me 'post a question' on SO.

[image: 2 moving dots in an endless loop while 'Post your question' gets grayed out]

Comment: Have you tried copying the body and retrying after refresh?

Comment: That first paragraph looks like it is formatted as code and I'm pretty sure the quality filters block that. Should show an message ... any errors in the developer console of your browser?

Comment: @rene I was able to reproduce the OP's problem. In the console I see "Uncaught Svg icon getters must be initialized before an icon can be retrieved" and "Assertion failed: Input argument is not an HTMLInputElement" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" at onloadwff.js:71

Comment: @rene: I'm sorry- how do I access the developer console of my browser?

Comment: depending on Browser and OS but I normally hit F12 on my keyboard.

Comment: @KodosJohnson that is strange: I don't have that onloadwff.js script.

Comment: The question you're trying to post is not a great one, and is likely to be closed even if you're successful in posting it.  Can you read the Help Center articles, browse some questions that have been received favorably by the community, and then write a new question with that guidance in mind?

Comment: @rene Sorry it looks like the issue is the first error which is "Uncaught Svg icon getters must be initialized before an icon can be retrieved" at full-anon.en.js?v=75db11586d68:5. Also the error happens infrequently. Sometimes the error shows and sometimes I get the input validation errors that you would expect.

Comment: @rene the onloadwff.js errors was occurring on one of my browser extensions so you can ignore those other errors. I was able to reproduce the problem in incognito mode with all my extensions disabled and the first error (with full-anon.en.js) still shows.

Comment: @robert harvey: I'm sorry if my screenshot caused any confusion. The screenshot only shows the last paragraph in my question. I have provided a lot of context and my code samples as well, in the previous paragraphs (not part of the screenshot).

Comment: Well, the code formatting looks really odd for a paragraph that's not actually code.  Can you remove it and try posting again?

Comment: @shaw38 can you see if you have any validation messages under the textarea when you try to post?

Comment: @rene: I've asked generic questions (without code samples) on SO before, and this is the 1st time I'm posting code samples. I just used <code>..</code> to indicate code blocks- I'm  not sure if that is the right approach.  This is the error I see : 'Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.' ...Would sharing my formatted_question help?

Comment: @Kodos Johnson: ^

Comment: Do you see all the text in your screenshot that is grayed out?  That is *code formatting.*  And you're doing it on text that is not code.  *Remove it.*

Comment: @rene after further investigation, I'm not sure if the error is preventing users from posting, it just doesn't cause the validation message to be styled correctly. The specific problem by the OP is probably just because their post has formatting problems.

Comment: @KodosJohnson: Can you let me know the correct way to indicate a code block? And the correct way to distinguish table_names from normal text, display-wise?

Comment: @KodosJohnson: so far, I've been using <code>...</code> to display both things- code blocks, as well as to distinguish table_names from normal text.

Comment: don't use <code></code> markup. Either select the text and click the `{}` button in the toolbar, or hit ctrl+K; or indent the code with 4 spaces.

Comment: It looks like in your question, you didn't close a <code> tag, so part of your paragraph has code formatting. Just make sure you close it. Also, for code blocks, you can just highlight your code and click the double bracket (`{}`) symbol in the editor. That will turn it into a code block. You can also use code fences: just put 3 tildes (`~~~`) before and after your code block.

Comment: @robert harvey: I have removed the formatting for the last paragraph that didn't contain code. Seems like I have formatting issues in the previous paragraphs that are preventing me from posting my question. So, I've asked some users for the ways to correctly format code blocks and specific_object_names , in my previous comments. Would you happen to know of any suggestions to this effect?

Comment: For inline code, you can just surround the variable names with backticks (`)

Comment: see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126236/im-getting-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatted-as  and also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113810/incomprehensible-your-post-appears-to-contain-code-that-is-not-properly-formatt#comment359337_130733

Comment: @rene: Guys, it's solved. Y'all were so helpful. Thanks a bunch for being proactive with my query.  I will post the answer below. The error in being unable to post had to do with incorrect formatting in my code sample.

Answer (score 4):

The error in being unable to post had to do with incorrect formatting in my code sample. Strangely, there were no error messages showing up until I logged out and logged back in- it was just an endless stream of dots running across my screen for an hour.

To indicate a code_block, I was using < code>   < /code> , I should have been doing this:  select the text and click the {} button in the toolbar.

For now, to distinguish between normal text and *table_names*, I drew emphasis to the *table_names* by clicking the 'I' button in the Toolbar.

Comment: I've tracked down the cause of this; we rolled back the code responsible & will correct it before deploying again. Thanks for reporting it!