# Cannot ask question on Stack Overflow - "Your post contains improperly formatted code"

Tags: support, asking-questions

I tried to ask a question on Stack Overflow, but I cannot ask my question. I receive an error message that says my post contains improperly formatted code,

I am pretty sure it does. [Here's a PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/FwaXP3K2) with the original question.

How do I fix this and still get my answer on Stack Overflow?

Comment: you have to include only the problematic part of the code and ask question on that

Comment: Try using markdown syntax to form your URL rather than HTML; `[index.html](http://www.destiny-craft.com/index.html)` (instead of `<a href="http://www.destiny-craft.com/index.html> index.html </a>`). However, you *really* need to look at http://sscce.org/ before you post your question, and greatly reduce the amount of code you're posting. Also look at using capital letters (*I* rather than *i*), and removing salutations, otherwise you risk not getting your question answered by showing a lack of formatting/ research effort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume the random linebreaks in your code [confused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113813/220538)  the Markdown editor. Anyway, I've fixed the question for you. Here's the [markup](http://pastebin.com/fn1Ufs98). (note that I've also removed '*hello*', '*regards*' etc. from your question and improved the formatting a bit).

Apart from that, I do not think it is a very good question. It contains 300+ lines of code; I doubt anyone will go through all of that and answer your question. If you want to get good and accurate answers, reduce your code to a minimum and explain your issue clearly.

See also: [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: No doubt at all about it being too much code; 300+ lines of code badly fails "Make it relevant to others" on [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), @milo.